# Eclipse EGit/JGit with LFS : commit looks ok but it doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, github, egit, jgit, git-lfs

I want to enable LFS for my project, hosted on GitHub. I use Neon with EGit/JGit 4.7.0.201704051617.
I also have git/2.12.2.windows.2 and git-lfs/2.1.0 .

Just for test, I do :

```
git lfs track "*.dll"
```

If I had a .dll file and commit, github show this kind of content for the file :

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:f81cee5f00c704e18b1c0372e026d2a0f56ff0957d37835c9ca36d6fef2bdcef
size 1024
```

Then the pull failed for egit and even for git. So I have to delete this entry.

If I commit using git command line, the file is ok on github and egit can pull it.

I do many tries without success. My testing repo is here : https://github.com/nicolas-albert/TestGit

Comment: The newest EGit (4.8.x) seems to upload the file content above to Git LFS instead of the binary file. Not sure that's an improvement... If you can, use IntelliJ. Unfortunately we can't over here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your .gitconfig to reference the LFS filters using:

```
git lfs install
```

Having done that you set up your project's .gitattributes file to specify which files should be managed by LFS.  Then generally use standard Git commands with no need to reference LFS commands directly.

```
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```